# error ctor is not defined

Tags: c++, windows, constructor, poco-libraries

I have the following code that works on Linux but doesn't work on Windows(VS2008)

```
URI(): Poco::URI::URI();
```

I get the following errors:

```
error C2039: '{ctor}' : is not a member of 'Poco::URI'
error C2437: 'URI': already initialized
```

I made the following changes to:

```
URI(){ Poco::URI::URI(); }
```

Do the two lines of code mean the same? And why doesn't the first one line of code don't work on Windows?

edit:
I am using the Poco Library, so this is code I have:

```
#include Poco/URI.h
class URI : public Poco::URI
{
public:
    URI(): Poco::URI::URI(){}
};
```

Poco/URI.h

```
namespace Poco {

class URI
{
public:
    URI::URI():
_port(0){}
private:
unsigned short _port;
};
```

Comment: Post more contextual code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right way to do the following:

```
URI() : Poco::URI(){}
```

I was including a namespace `URI` that did not exist.

Also:

Poco::URI::URI(){} // works when using gcc compiler but not on a windows compiler

Answer (score 1):

No, they don't mean the same. The latter creates a temporary, anonymous `Poco::URI::URI` object inside the `URI` constructor.

Comment: "declares a function inside the constructor" - it *calls* a function (maybe a ctor of another class), not "declares"

Comment: @kol: oops, thinko! Corrected the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but my guess would be that this:

```
URI(): Poco::URI::URI();
```

is like trying to pass an initialization list to a constructor with no implementation.
On the other hand

```
URI(){ Poco::URI::URI(); }
```

this is clearly a constructor definition and implementation. The first one gives an error because you're "using" a constructor for initialization purpose while it doesn't properly exist.